# WebViewPage.Model vs WebViewPage.ViewData.Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am reading about ASP.NET MVC and somehow bewildered at those two objects.

Reading through tutorials and some books they seem to be representing the same object (object value?).

How are they different?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.model(v=vs.118).aspx   vs      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.model(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are the same object.**

The `WebViewPage` type is what views are. When you use `@Model.OrderNumber` you are using the `Model` property of the `WebViewPage`.

The property code looks like this:

```
public abstract class WebViewPage : WebPageBase, IViewDataContainer, IViewStartPageChild
{
    [ ... ]

    public object Model
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ViewData.Model;
        }
    }
}
```

We can assume that the `WebViewPage` was given the property (as read-only) so that you could type `@Model` and not `@ViewData.Model`.

Comment: So basically it is a shortcut. Thank you :)